# adapter is refreshed on second notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, quickblox, quickblox-android

the Adapter won't refresh unless notifyDataSetChanged is executed two times!
but when I track it in the debugger it works perfectly!
That problem happens only on **sendRequest** method, it works perfectly fine on other methods!

```
      if (friendListHelper.isFriendRequestAlreadySent(user.getId())) {
            holder.addFriendBtn.setText("Cancel Request");
            holder.addFriendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    cancelRequest(view, user, position);
}
           });
        } else if (friendListHelper.isFriend(user.getId())) {
            holder.addFriendBtn.setText("Unfriend");
            holder.addFriendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    deleteFriend(view, position, user);
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.addFriendBtn.setText("Add Friend");
            holder.addFriendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    sendRequest(user, view, position);
                }
            });
        }
    }


     private void deleteFriend(final View view, final int position, QBUser user) {
            friendListHelper.removeFriend(user, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            });
        }

        private void cancelRequest(final View view, QBUser user, final int position) {
            friendListHelper.cancelFriendRequest(user.getId(), new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }

        }

        private void sendRequest(final QBUser user, final View view, final int position) {
            friendListHelper.sendFriendRequest(user, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Debugging is one way of tracking the behavior of your code. But, try logging to the logcat with `Log` to see if the `sendRequest()` method is being triggered properly.

Comment: Yes I've already tested log and it's called correctly.